# Backreferencing in PHP to JS regexp translation

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I must rewrite this code in JS :

```
        $formateTweet = preg_replace("/http([^ ]*)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http\\1\">http\\1</a>", $formateTweet);          
        $formateTweet = preg_replace("/@([^ ]*)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/\\1\">@\\1</a>", $formateTweet);
        $formateTweet = preg_replace("/#([^ ]*)/", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\\1\">#\\1</a>", $formateTweet);
```

I wrote :

```
    formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/http([^ ]*)/, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http\\1\">http\\1</a>");            
    formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/@([^ ]*)/, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/\\1\">@\\1</a>");
    formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/#([^ ]*)/, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=%23\\1\">#\\1</a>");
```

But with no success. For example for tweet "@test bla bla" i get

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/\1">@\1</a> bla bla
```

while i should get

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/test">@test</a> bla bla
```

I guess I must change the regexps but what should I write instead ? I think the issue comes from the "1" that doesn't get the value from the matcher

Comment: define "no success". What is happening? What should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's what you intended, but this should be pretty much rewrite of PHP code above:

```
formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/http([^ ]*)/g, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http$1\">http$1</a>");
formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/@([^ ]*)/g, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>");
formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/#([^ ]*)/g, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=$1\">#$1</a>");
```

What I did was:

1. Add `g` modifier to replace multiple occurrences.
2. Added `$1` placeholder for capture groups in regexp.

Answer (score 2):

For backreferrencing in javascript use `$1` instead of `\\1`.

```js
formattedTweet = "@test bla bla";
formattedTweet = formattedTweet.replace(/@([^ ]*)/, "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>");
console.log(formattedTweet);
```

Outputs

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/test">@test</a> bla bla
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Robin. I upvote yours but I accept miloss's which is more complete. (you already have enough rep don't you ) :)